# how to exclude some of the matches from grep?

Tags: grep, find, ack

I am using grep to printout the matching lines from a very large file
from which i got hundreds of matches, some of them are not interesting i want to exclude those matching which are not interesting

`grep "WARNING" | grep -v "WARNING_HANDLING_THREAD" path` # i tried this

**When I grep the file for warning I get**

> 0-00:00:33.392 (2127:127:250:02 =     21.278532       Fri Feb  1 10:17:22 2019) <3:0x000a>:[89]:[enter]: cest_handleFreeReq.c:116:  [WARNING]: cest_handleFreeReq: sent from DECA ->UCS
>
> 0-00:00:38.263 (2189:022:166:06 =     21.891510       Fri Feb  1 10:17:28 2019) <3:0x000a>:[89]:[enter]: cest_handleConfigReq.c:176:  [WARNING]: cest_handleConfigReq.c: GroupConfig NOT present.
>
> 0-00:00:38.263 (2189:022:167:03 =     21.891510       Fri Feb  1 10:17:28 2019) <3:0x000a>:[89]:[enter]: cest_handleConfigReq.c:194:  [WARNING]: cest_handleConfigReq: physicalConfig NOT present.
>
> 60 0x6d77   0  0x504ea | 2 18  | 0  0  | 4  12 | 647   | 14685 0   0.0 0   500 500 | 0 | 0 | 38    | ETH_DRV_WARNING_HANDLING_thread
>   60  0   | 0 0   | 0 0   0   | 0  0   0   0   0   0  ! N/A   N/A N/A N/A N/A N/A |ETH_DRV_WARNING_HANDLING_thread
>
> WARNING: List of threads violating the heap & stack limit

**I want to exclude the last lines which are not interesting**

> 0-00:00:33.392 (2127:127:250:02 =     21.278532       Fri Feb  1 10:17:22 2019) <3:0x000a>:[89]:[enter]: cest_handleFreeReq.c:116:  [WARNING]: cest_handleFreeReq: sent from DECA ->UCS
>
> 0-00:00:38.263 (2189:022:166:06 =     21.891510       Fri Feb  1 10:17:28 2019) <3:0x000a>:[89]:[enter]: cest_handleConfigReq.c:176:  [WARNING]: cest_handleConfigReq.c: GroupConfig NOT present.
>
> 0-00:00:38.263 (2189:022:167:03 =     21.891510       Fri Feb  1 10:17:28 2019) <3:0x000a>:[89]:[enter]: cest_handleConfigReq.c:194:  [WARNING]: cest_handleConfigReq: physicalConfig NOT present.

Is there a way to do this using grep find or any other tool?

Thank you

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus i didn't get what you are asking, the blocks in the question above is the sample output when did grep and immediate block is the output how i what the results to look like. have a log file from which i am grepping the word warning but i want to exclude some warnings like violating stack and heap limit lines i want to know how to do that to exclude some of the lines which are not interesting from grep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the substring `thread` is in lower case in the data, but in upper case in your expression.

Instead, use

```
grep -F 'WARNING' logfile | grep -F -v 'WARNING_HANDLING_thread'
```

The `-F` make `grep` use string comparisons rather than regular expression matching (this is not *really* related to your current issue, but just a way of showing that we know what type of pattern we're matching with).

Another option would be to make the second `grep` do case insensitive matching with `-i`:

```
grep -F 'WARNING' logfile | grep -Fi -v 'WARNING_HANDLING_THREAD'
```

In this case though, I would probably match the `[WARNING]` tag instead:

```
grep -F '[WARNING]:' logfile
```

Note that here we *need* the `-F` so that `grep` interprets the pattern as a string and not as a regular expression matching any single character out of the `W`, `A`, `R`, `N`, `I`, `G` set, followed by a `:`.

Comment: this is just an sample trace log, i also have some uninterested things with '[WARNING]:' my bad i haven't made that thing clear in my question. but if i use **grep -F 'WARNING' | grep -F -v 'WARNING_HANDLING_thread'** it is printing the whole log not only the lines which has WARNING excluding the second grep content

Comment: @kuchu Huh? How can you get the _whole_ log?  I'm assuming that you either pipe the log to the first `grep` or that you use `grep -F 'WARNING' logfile | grep -F -v '...other string ...'`, right?

Comment: **grep -F 'ERROR' | grep -F -v 'WARNING_HANDLING_thread' logfile** this is what i am using @kusalananda

Comment: @kuchu The first `grep` would do _nothing_ there. Give the logfile to the first `grep`. The second `grep` should read the output of the first `grep`, not the logfile.  I have updated the answer to reflect this.